# PHP json_encode outputs numbers with quotes

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, google-visualization

I have an array generated with the following code where $result is a collection with Salesman a string field and col1 an integer field

```
        $data=[];

        $arr = ($result->get());
        $j=0;
        foreach($arr as $res)
        {
            $data[$j] = [$res->shortName,$res->col1];
            $j++;
        }
```

And when i pass this array to Google Charts using json_encode like

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({!!  json_encode($data)  !!}
```

it is rendered in Javascript as:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["John","700000"],["Jessa","1400000"],["Mercy ","1100000"],["William","780000"],["Thomas","550000"]]
                  );
```

As you can see the integer numbers are also rendered as strings with a quote. Is there any way to avoid this ?

Comment: Cast to int : (int)$res->col1

Comment: How do you know those fields are integers, not strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you only need to convert the type of your values in PHP, like this:

```
$data[$j] = [$res->shortName, intval( $res->col1 ) ];
```

This way all your `$res->col1` values will be stored as int. If you want float values just use `floatval` instead of `intval`, like this:

```
$data[$j] = [$res->shortName, floatval( $res->col1 ) ];
```